# Retrieve details of selected object with AJAX [SilverStripe]

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I have a select box which contains all the teams in the DB in the table 'Team'. Each team plays for one or more divisions which are in the Division table. A team has many divisions and a division has many teams.

I am new to Ajax and need to retrieve all the divisions a team plays for when that team is selected in the dropdown field. Which code must i implement on the back and front end to achieve this? How can I pass the selected team with Ajax for it to return me some divisions? I understand I need PHP code to handle the request, but how do I pass the selected team so PHP knows what it needs to return?

Thanks. If you need some code let me know (but i haven't got any so far to handle this).

Comment: What did you do so far?

Comment: Nothing so far, I have the select box, but nothing happens when I select a team. I haven't attempted an Ajax call or PHP function as I don't know how to pass the selected team with Ajax to PHP.

Comment: Well, it's basically javascript on the client, on select event call some URL to get data from a controller, insert it somehow. Reminds me of the functionality of the tagfield,https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-tagfield , maybe it helps you to analyse that code.

Comment: @JackO'Connor - Have you gone through [Lesson 17 Ajax Behaviour and ViewableData](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ajax-behaviour-and-viewabledata)? This should give help a lot